# output of argmin cannot be changed to numeric

Tags: r, mapply

For the following example:

```
    f<-function(x,y){x^2+y^2}
mm<-c(0.2,0.5,0.3)

inputs<- list(c(1,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(0,0,1))
outputs<-mapply(f,inputs,mm )
argmin<-inputs[which.min(outputs)]
argmin-mm
```

i get the error: 
Error in argmin - mm : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I was wondering, how can I get it so that `argmin` is a numeric and I can perform something like :

`argmin +mm` etc

I've tried to set `as.numeric` to `argmin`, but i get another warning:

(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: from where is the function RelativeEntropy() ? what says: `str(argmin)`

Comment: @jogo sorry i forgot to change it to the working example of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputs` is a list and `mm` is a vector

try

`unlist(argmin) - mm`

or

`armign[[1]] - mm`